# Customizing UserChangeForm in django

Tags: python, django

I want to delete the 'groups' field from the build-in UserChangeForm and add my own "Role' field. How to handle that? I created my class which inherits from UserChangeForm and went to somehow delete but no change.

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.fields)

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        fields = ()
        exclude = ('groups',)


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    change_form = CustomUserChangeForm
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        UserAdmin.list_display = ('username', 'is_active', 'email',
                                  'date_joined', 'user_role', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')


class RoleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'role_permissions')


admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(Role, RoleAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit the `Meta` of the `UserChangeForm` and rewrite the `exclude` field to exclude the `groups`:

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        fields = None
        exclude = ('groups',)
```

For the admin site you can work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    list_display = ('username', 'is_active', 'email', 'date_joined',
                    'user_role', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')

User = get_user_model()

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Seems to don't work. I edited the post with code that I use to register CustomUserAdmin

Comment: @LSD: you should *not* pass `change_form = CustomUserChangeForm()`, but `form = CustomUserChangeForm`, so a *reference* to the *form class*, so *not* `change_form`, and not calling the constructor.

Comment: Ohh, but unfortunately nothing changes, still the groups field is in this form.

Comment: @LSD: that's likely because you forgot to first *unregister* the existing model admin... See edit.

Comment: I have unregistered. I edited with admin.py code

Comment: @LSD: did you use `form = CustomUserChangeForm`?

Comment: @LSD: you should also *not* set `fields = ()`. `None` and `()` are *not* the same. By setting `fields = ()`, you basically remove *all* form fields.

Comment: Now i get ""Key 'groups' not found in 'UserForm'. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, password, user_permissions, username."" After rename change_form to form

Comment: @LSD: it seems that you used a `UserForm`, not the `CustomUserChangeForm`.

Comment: @LSD: did you by any change specify a *custom* user model?

Comment: No i use the build-in django user model. I have registered User in admin panel with my custom admin view.

Comment: @LSD: can you edit the question with the full traceback?

Comment: I figure out that problem, now I can't add here my custom Role model.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted UserChangeForm, and I define fieldsets in CustomUseAdmin like this:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L45

And works correctly, but I can't add my 'Role' model here

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_role', 'user_permissions'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        UserAdmin.list_display = ('username', 'is_active', 'email',
                                  'date_joined', 'user_role', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')
```

Unknown field(s) (user_role) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CustomUserAdmin.

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user_role", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name="role_permissions")
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'auth'
```